# Proving function's injectivity

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$$f(X/A)\subseteq Y/f(A) \forall A\subseteq X \leftrightarrow f= \mbox{injective}$$

I know that I should prove this in 2 ways. First I should assume that the first part is true and f is not injective, that should conclude in contradiction. Secondly I should assume that f is injective and show that $f(X/A)$ belongs to $Y/f(A) \forall A\subseteq X$ . I'm having trouble proving this.

Comment: It seems like people have figured out what you meant, but your notation is a bit confusing.  (1) Although "$\forall A \subseteq X$" means "for every subset $A$ of $X$", which can go at the beginning or end of the sentence, quantifier symbols as in "$\forall A \subseteq X$" should always go at the beginning. (2) Set difference is usually written $\setminus$ instead of $/$.  (3) What are $f$, $X$, and $Y$?  Is $f$ a function from $X$ to $Y$?

Answer (score 1):

For the $\implies$ direction, assume that $X$ has at least two elements, otherwise the injectivity is trivial. Take $A=\{x\}$ and take $y\ne x$. Now just use the inclusion, noting that $y\in X\setminus A$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f$ be injective. Let $x\in f(X\setminus A)$. Therefore there exists $y\in X\setminus A$ such that $f(y)=x$. Thus $f(y)=x\notin f(A)$ as $f$ is injective. hence the result.